# PHP foreach loop doesn't appear into two rows

Tags: php, html, css

Executing this code I get a list of categories. It is displayed like this

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
<tr>
 <td align="right">
    <legend><?php _e( 'Category', self::nspace ); ?></legend>
 </td>
 <td>
    <div class="radio-group">
       <?php foreach ( $this->get_media_categories() as $slug => $name ): ?>
       <label>
             <tr>
                <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="media-categories[]" value="<?php echo $slug; ?>"<?php if ( in_array( $slug, $_REQUEST['media-categories'] ) ): ?> checked<?php endif; ?>> 
                   <?php echo $name; ?>
                </td>
             </tr>

       </label>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

I want it to be displayed in two columns like this :

```
category X        category X
category X        category X
category X        category X
category X        category X
category X        category X
```

My question is how should I break for each loop to make it look like that?

EDIT:
Here is the whole code:

```
<form id="mediacat-library-search-form" action="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/<?php if ( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ): ?><?php echo $this->settings_data['rewrite_url']; ?><?php else: ?>?page_id=11735<?php endif; ?>" method="post">
  <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align: right;" >
    <div class="cols two-cols table-responsive table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <legend><?php _e( 'Category', self::nspace ); ?></legend>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="radio-group">
          <?php foreach ( $this->get_media_categories() as $slug => $name ): ?>
          <label>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="media-categories[]" value="<?php echo $slug; ?>"<?php if ( in_array( $slug, $_REQUEST['media-categories'] ) ): ?> checked<?php endif; ?>> 
    <?php echo $name; ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </label>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <legend><?php _e( 'Keyword', self::nspace ); ?></legend>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="form-row" id="mediacat-library-keyword">
          <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" value="<?php if ( isset( $_REQUEST['keyword'] ) ) echo $_REQUEST['keyword']; ?>">
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <td align="center" >
        <input type="hidden" name="mediacat_library_submit" value="1">
        <input type="submit"  style=" border: 2px solid #006a4e; background: #ffffff; text-shadow: #ffffff 0 1px 0; padding: 9px 18px; color: #006a4e; font-size: 14px; font-family: helvetica, serif; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer;"  value="<?php _e( 'Search', self::nspace ); ?>">
      </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<?php if ( isset( $_REQUEST['keyword'] ) || isset( $_REQUEST['media-categories'] ) )  $this->mediacat_library( true ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this just by using the CSS `column-count`:

```
.radio-group {
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Comment: column count works for block element, here it is about the table

Comment: yes correct we can achieve this using CSS 3 feature. I have given solution using php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Any way I tried this way, nothing is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use counter to track and break into columns. Please check below code.

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">
       <legend><?php _e( 'Category', self::nspace ); ?></legend>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="radio-group">
          <?php 
              $count = 0;
              foreach ( $this->get_media_categories() as $slug => $name ): ?>
          <?php if(($count%2) == 0) : ?>
           <label>
                <tr>
          <?php endif; ?>           
                   <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="media-categories[]" value="<?php echo $slug; ?>"<?php if ( in_array( $slug, $_REQUEST['media-categories'] ) ): ?> checked<?php endif; ?>> 
                      <?php echo $name; ?>
                   </td>
           <?php if(($count%2) == 0) : ?>
                </tr>
           </label>
          <?php endif; ?>
           <?php $count++; ?>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
       </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  
I tried this it in fact it changes only my style but still it didn't divide it into two rows ? Please check I edited my question, I did add the whole code maybe there's a conflict that I can't notice @RuchishParikh

Comment: It would print - `<td><div class="radio-group"><tr ...` ,which is wrong HTML structure.

Comment: first time 0 then it will print with <tr><td>.

Answer (score 0):

You are using row for each column. You need to close `tr` after every 2 `td`s with proper `table` structure. Currently you are printing `tr`s inside `td`. Try -

```
<div class="radio-group">
   <table>
   <tr>
   <?php 
   $i = 0;
   foreach ( $this->get_media_categories() as $slug => $name ): 
   ?>
            <td>
               <input type="checkbox" name="media-categories[]" value="<?php echo $slug; ?>"<?php if ( in_array( $slug, $_REQUEST['media-categories'] ) ): ?> checked<?php endif; ?>> 
               <?php echo $name; ?>
            </td>
   <?php
   $i++; 
   if($i%2 == 0) {
      echo "</tr><tr>";
   }
   endforeach; 
   ?>
   </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Another solution would be -

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ( $this->get_media_categories() as $slug => $name ): ?>
    <li>
         <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="media-categories[]" value="<?php echo $slug; ?>"<?php if ( in_array( $slug, $_REQUEST['media-categories'] ) ): ?> checked<?php endif; ?>> 
                <?php echo $name; ?>
         </label>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

And **CSS** would be -

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    /*rest of the styles*/
}
```

Comment: But If I remove tables I have other elements there? Should I include this inside table? Please check  I posted the whole page? thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like following:

I have not tested this code but I think it will work. It is a simple combination of counter.

```
<?php
$tdCount = 0;
$tabletd = ''; 
foreach ( $this->get_media_categories() as $slug => $name ): ?>
           <label>
                <?php if($tdCount == 2) { ?>
                 <tr>
                    <?php echo $tabletd;?>
                 </tr>
                 <?php
                    $tdCount = 0;
                    $tabletd = ''; 
                  }
                    $tdCount++;
                    $checked = '';
                    if ( in_array( $slug, $_REQUEST['media-categories'] ) ){ $checked = 'checked';}
                    $tabletd.= '<td>
             <input type="checkbox" name="media-categories[]" value="'.$slug.'" '.$checked.'> 
             '.$name.'
                     </td>';
                   ?>

           </label>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php if($tabletd!= '')  {?>
<label>
                 <tr>
                    <?php echo $tabletd;?>
                 </tr>
           </label>
<?php } ?>
```